GitHub Desktop - "Create pull request" greyed out
I need to use 2 different instances of GitHub Enterprise. (N.B. I'm not using GitHub.com at all).
GitHub Desktop only seems to allow me to be logged in to one instance of GitHub Enterprise at a time.
I've therefore setup an SSH key, used this on both GitHub Enterprise instances, and cloned my repos via SSH.
I am able to fetch and commit changes. However, Create pull request is greyed out in GitHub Desktop, and so I need to switch to the web UI to create the PR, rather than neatly managing it within GitHub Desktop.
N.B. I've checked that I have the affected branch selected, and GitHub Desktop says No local changes.
Is being 'logged in' to GitHub Desktop required to create a pull request? If so, any recommendations on how I can work with 2 separate GitHub Enterprise instances?

If you switching too often , using web interface will be good idea

GitHub Desktop uses the authentication credentials tied to your logged-in account to use GitHub API
if you can create a multiple users in the OS you can run 2 instance of GitHub Desktop.

Having multiple accounts signed in is currently not available and is a proposal.  (https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3707)
For the greyed out button for creating pull requests. Can you take a look at https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/17502 ?
